# 170 MB Hello World -> Deploying apps with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, dll, qt-creator

I'm new to Qt but no problem in the C++. I used Qt Creator and made a simple program with a button (like a hello world) then I built the project. I was not able to run the executable file in windows itself (outside the creator) because it needed these DLL files:

```
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
mingwm10.dll
QtGuid4.dll
QtCored4.dll
```

I found these files and put them beside the exe. Now the program works but the folder has a size of 170 MB because of the **big** Dll files. Is this a way of deploying Qt applications. I know their's a way to make a standalone static app but that's not the problem. I'm ok with the dlls but the dependencies seem to be too big. Is there a different method of deploying projects with smaller file sizes?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried release versions of qt dlls ?

Comment: Yeah, but it says: "The procedure entry point _Z5qFreePv could not be located in the dynamic link library QtCore4.dll". I then found another QtCore4.dll in this folder: /qt/bin and used that but then it said: "The procedure entry point ??1QSettings@@UAE@XZ could not be located in the dynamic link library QtCore4.dll".

Comment: I think that you need to compile your application in release mode in order to use the release version of Qt dlls.

Comment: tibur is right, build your app in release mode: CONFIG += release CONFIG -=debug CONFIG -=debug_and_release

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why don't you do a release build and use the release dlls instead of the debug dlls which are much larger.

Since this is regarding size:

Debug libraries

QtCored4.dll = ~37MB

QtGui4d.dll  = ~157MB

Release libraries

QtCore.dll   = ~2.3Mb

QtGui4.dll   = ~9MB

(from looking at the sizes in my Qt\version\bin directory)

Comment: Didn't catch this being mentioned in the comments to the original post before I posted this. But it is a valid answer to the question so I believe it should go here...

Answer (score 3):

you have two problems here:

- "procedure entry point not found": you have multiple versions of Qt libraries installed. Not good. You are linking against import library A, while at runtime your executable finds a dll B, which is not the one you linked against. Check your project output while linking to see which import library VS uses. Easiest solution: delete/uninstall everything Qt related and start over cleanly. Adjust your project settings likewise.
- not finding the dlls at runtime: solution is to add the directory with qt dlls to your PATH

Comment: That doesn't help the distribution problem though when the DLLs themselves are 170 MB.

Comment: I know that; other people already pointed out that was because of the debug build, so I didn't repeat that information..

Comment: "you have multiple versions of Qt libraries installed"- Can you give a solution on that. I'm using QtSDK and I I have 4.8 4.7 both

Comment: @Dewsworld you should start a new question for such problems, containing details on how to reproduce them

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to deploy statically linked version of a Qt application, you should consider building custom versions of the libraries where you [disable all the features](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/fine-tuning-features.html) you don't need, thus minimizing the size of the libraries.

Comment: Statically linking requires a proper commercial Qt license FWIW.

Comment: @Rob: Qt is available under the LGPL, you don't need a commercial license to statically link with it as long as your application is LGPL as well.  However there are lots of other issues as stated here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/deployment.html