# QtXmld4.dll was not found

Tags: qt, dll, environment-variables

I have Qt 4.6.3 installed at C:\Qt\4.6.3 (Windows).

I just compiled a Qt application and went to run the EXE.  When double-clicking on the executable, saw an error message:

"This application has failed to start because QtXmld4.dll was not found.  Re-installing the application may fix this problem."

Found QtXmld4.dll in C:\Qt\4.6.3\lib.  When copying this file into the same directory as the executable, I no longer see this error, but instead the same error for the Qt core DLL.

Is there an environment variable I should have set so these libraries are found?

Current Qt environment variables:
Path = C:\Qt\4.6.3\lib;C:\Qt\4.6.3\bin;C:\Qt\4.6.3\include;%PATH%
QMAKESPEC = C:\Qt\4.6.3\mkspecs\win32-g++
QTDIR = C:\Qt\4.6.3
QTLIB = C:\Qt\4.6.3\lib

TIA

Comment: Note that the QtXmld4.dll is a debug version of the dll (release version is QtXml4.dll). See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/3675450/362638 for more information about release and debug dlls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that `C:\Qt\4.6.3\lib` is on your system path environment variable.

The initial problem was solved because the dll is now local, but that dll obviously references `QtCore.dll` which will be in the same folder.

Did you restart your machine after installing Qt? It could have updated the path, but it would only take effect after the next restart.

Comment: The restart fixed it!  Thanks!